# ext js accordion center

Tags: javascript, extjs

My web application is at:

http://www.myethiopia.org/QuickLinks/main2.html

I have 2 issues:

- I can't open this in IE. It works in Firefox.
- My other issue is I want to display the links in the accordion in the center.

Comment: I'd recommend you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and try posting another question with a bit more detail letting us know what you've tried.

Comment: Click on the weather station on the left and click on any of the "Station" links.  It opens in a new page.  I want it open in the empty center panel.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

IE wants everything picture perfect :)

**Solution:**
Remove the comma at the end on line 35 of your file

```
['American Express Company',            52.55, 0.01,  0.02,  '9/1 12:00am'],
```

to

```
['American Express Company',            52.55, 0.01,  0.02,  '9/1 12:00am']
```

Tip: If you are starting to develop applications in ext-js, use ext-all-debug-w-comments.js instead of bootstrap.js or specify that file in bootstrap.js

Comment: Thanks Joza. That was pretty silly of me as I had fixed this issue a while ago.  I posted the wrong file to the server.  Thanks.

Comment: Use ext-all-debug-w-comments because I am assuming it is easier to debug???? Can you explain or provide a link that explains the benefit of using this js file? I am not able to find a good explanation for this file in ext js' site.

Comment: There are three types of files in the extjs folder - ext-all.js (Intended for you to use on production systems),ext-all-debug.js (This gives you a debug functionality) and ext-all-debug-w-comments.js (This gives you meaningful output on the console if you have any errors on your code). You could refer this url - http://www.rivellomultimediaconsulting.com/html5-framework-senchas-ext-js-4-helloworld/?doing_wp_cron=1338039043